# How to convert a list of DataFrame columns (len(list) == len(df)) into a list of column values at the respective list idx?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

Given a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col0': [3, 4, 5, -3, -4, -5],
     'col1': [6, 7, 8, -6, -7, -8], 
     'col2': [9, 10, 11, -9, -10, -11], 
     'col3': [12, 13, 14, -12, -13, -14], 
     'col4': [15, 16, 17, -15, -16, -17]}
    )
```

and a list of df column names with the strict condition of being the same length as df

```
cols = ['col4', 'col4', 'col1', 'col3', 'col0', 'col2']
```

The following list comprehension calls to each df column at the index of the column in cols:

```
vals = [df[col][i] for col, i in zip(cols, df.index)]
```

Resulting in a list of values

```
vals
>>> [15, 16, 5, -12, -4, -11]
```

What techniques would you use to get the same results as vals?
Any modules are welcome, and execution time comparisons are ultra welcome.

EDIT:
Resulting in a list of values

```
vals
>>> [15, 16, 8, -12, -4, -11]
```

Comment: The `vals` you have provided looks like it was produced using `cols` with a value of `'col0'` (not `'col1'`) at index 2.

Comment: @constantstranger you are right!

Comment: Imho you can save quite a bit of time by replacing `df[col][i]` with `df.at[i, col]`.

Comment: Interesting question, btw.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use transpose of the dataframe, so you will have columns as indices and then more importantly you want to take the diagonal of the transposed df, because of the way you want to access the specific items. So use [`numpy.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html)

```
np.diag(df.T.loc[cols]).tolist()
```

output:

```
[15, 16, 8, -12, -4, -11]
```

Comment: Seems to take about only 20% of the time of the original solution.

Comment: @SomeDude can you elaborate a bit more as to why np.diag works in this case? Having trouble wrapping my mind around it.

Comment: @SomeDude scratch that question, unless you want to answer. I think I figured it out. Thanks again

Comment: @Timus How did you come to the 20%? I've tried timeit and cProfile to compare the original, your `df.at[i, col]`, SomeDude's `np.diag`, and mozway's index lookup. The best time so far was your honest opinion of `df.at[i, col]`.

Comment: @cornifer I did use `timeit`. But performance measurement is notoriously tricky, since it depends on so many variables (environment, actual data, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

An efficient method that does not require you to upscale the DataFrame is to perform an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
idx, col = pd.factorize(cols)
vals = df.reindex(col, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

output:

```
array([ 15,  16,   8, -12,  -4, -11])
```